# Probability - Q so easy that I can't seem to solve it

Tags: probability, self-study

> Twenty students take an exam. Student A scored five out of ten and Student B scored eight out of ten. Every score (1 to 10) is equally likely. What is the chance of a random person out of the people that took the exam scoring higher than Student A, but lower than Student B?

So this is from a very basic quiz, no distributions or anything, just frequencies so far. It is a multiple choice question and the possible values are a) 0.8, b) 0.4, c) 0.2, d) 0.22

The random person would have to score either 6 or 7 and there is a 0.2 chance of falling into that range if scores are equally likely. What throws me off is: why does it matter how many people took the exam? The probability of score 6 or 7 must be 0.2 for the whole population of the world. Or is it that Student A and B are already out of the equation, so we are only counting with 18? But how does that matter? I must be having a mental block - can someone help, pls?

Comment: Where does the question state that the total number matters?  Many multiple choice questions include irrelevant information ("distractors").

Comment: I think this question is poorly worded. It makes it sound like A and B were among the 20 students taking the exam - but then a randomly chosen student who took the exam would have a 2/20 chance of being A or B, in which case they definitely wouldn't have scored 6 or 7. But 0.18 isn't among the allowed answers.

Comment: @fblundun I don't have any difficulties with the wording: taken as written, it is internally consistent and unambiguous.  It doesn't matter whether A and B were among those students, either (but it would be difficult to make sense of the question if they weren't).

Comment: @whuber I disagree, I think it’s a totally valid interpretation to think that they want the probability of *some* person out of the remaining 18 to score that 6 or 7 score with $1-0.8^{18}=0.982$ chance of occurring. This is not a law or language class and the ask should be quite clear from the question. Irrelevant information is one thing, but confusing wording imho destroys the very integrity of testing a students ability on the subject at hand.

Comment: @whuber I think the question can easily be interpreted as "Twenty students including A and B took the exam. Given that A scored 5 and B scored 8, what's the probability that a randomly picked student (possibly A or B) scored 6 or 7?" The answer would then be 0.18.

Comment: @blundun That looks like a response error to me.  I still cannot see where the wording is confusing.  Where does the question refer to the *remaining* 18 students?  The phrase "people who took the exam" *explicitly* refers to "twenty students."  A "randomly picked student" means one of the 20. Moreover, your calculation appears to assume a population of 18 students could actually have equal chances of each of ten scores--but that is mathematically impossible.

Comment: @whuber I interpreted "Every score is equally likely" to mean not "exactly 2 students get each score" but "prior to the exam, each student independently is equally likely to get each score". Under this interpretation we need to randomly pick a student who is not A or B (with probability 18/20) and that student needs to have scored 6 or 7 (with probability 1/5).

Comment: @fblundun I understand your interpretation but your solution doesn't look consistent with it.  Since each score of the ten possible scores is equally likely and you are evaluating the event $\{6,7\},$ its chance must be $2/10.$  Nothing in the question states or even suggests the randomly selected student cannot include A or B. In fact, it seems carefully worded to preclude that misinterpretation: that's why the phrase "out of the people who took the exam" appears.  A and B took the exam (obviously: they have scores). However, *that doesn't matter* under your interpretation.

Comment: @whuber: Suppose every score was equally likely a priori (i.e. all students' exam results are drawn from U{1/10,10/10}), but now we are told that students A & B scored 5/10 and 8/10. If we draw a random student from the group of 20, what is the probability that they scored 5/10? It's not 0.1. This is easy to verify in a (dumb) simulation: simulate many random N=20 samples from a Uniform, reject all that don't contain at least one 5/10 and one 10/10, then calculate the frequency of 5/10 in the remaining samples. You'll get (about) 0.1125, not 0.1.

Comment: @Ruben I am unable to see anything in the question that hints of such a rejection procedure.  But I think I understand your interpretation: you take this to be a *conditional probability* question.  That's reasonable in our abstract setting (provided we ignore the fact there are no related tags applied).  Whether it's reasonable in the original setting would have to be decided from the context (namely, what concepts the question might be assessing).

Comment: @whuber it is precisely because the randomly selected student can be A or B that they are not equally likely to get each of the 10 possible scores. If the randomly selected student is A or B, then they definitely did not score 6 or 7, because the question states that they scored 5 or 8! The expected total number of 6s and 7s in the group of 20, conditional on A and B getting 5 and 8, is only 18*0.2.

Comment: @whuber: I think the question is worded vaguely enough to admit the conditional probability interpretation. The statement "Every score (1 to 10) is equally likely." could refer to the sample or the population from which it is drawn. If it's the sample, then your interpretation is correct. If it's the population, then it seems to me we must condition on having observed A&B and thus knowing that the sample belongs to the subset of random N=20 samples from U{1/10,10/10} that contain those observed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random student will score $X$ points where $P(X = 6) = P(X=7) = 1/10.$
So $P(5 < X < 8) = 2/10 = 0.2.$ Answer (c).

I *does not* matter how many people took the exam. The question is about *one randomly chosen* student.

*Note:* There are authors who think it is ever so clever to clutter questions with irrelevant information in order to make sure you pay attention only to the facts that matter. Is this really a clever way to write textbooks? The answer depends on whether the aim is to teach reading or probability.

Comment: +1 for the comments in the end. I also dislike that someone could interpret this as finding the probability that *any* of the other 18 students scored a 6 or 7, which is $1-0.8^18=0.982$, only to get zero credit because of tricky writing and a somewhat ambiguous question. Thankfully this is multiple choice and that answer isn’t there, but it still is quite frustrating that they would do this.

Comment: @ColinHicks: While we're at it: Under what realistic model of student behavior would scores 1 through 10 be equally likely?

Comment: @Colin and Bruce: Neither of you really needs reminding, but such lack of realism and the incapability of the OP to respond to inquiries for clarification are the salient reasons why we treat self-study questions in such special ways.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded. @whuber, I don't understand your "incapability of the OP to respond" comment: I posted the question yesterday evening, it is now the following morning - please allow me some time. The question was an online quiz, as indicated in my original post, and I do not have any more information, or ways to clarify it more. I totally agree with the comments that the "any score is equally likely" part is completely dumb - to me it says that no matter what you achieve in the exam, your score will be defined by a lottery.

Comment: Reader: Your comment elucidates my meaning: " I do not have any more information, or ways to clarify it more." That's exactly the difficulty we face with all textbook, exam, and other self-study questions: they come out of the blue, often unexplained, and usually there is nowhere one can go to learn about their motivation or context.  The problem isn't with the student, but with the very nature of the question.